# In laravel how to get the join table data in same array without where condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have created both employes and employes_detail tabel with the data

> i have created model for both of the table that is given below:

```
emloye model:

<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Model\EmployeDetail;
class Employe extends Model
{
    public function employes_detail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(EmployeDetail::class);
    }
}
```

and eployedetail model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployeDetail extends Model
{
   public function employe()
    {
        public function employe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employe::class);
    }
    }
}
```

and in controller i used like :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Model\Employe;
use App\Http\Model\EmployeDetail;
class EmployeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $Employe=Employe::all();
        $convert=$Employe->toArray();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($convert);exit;
        //return view('employe.employe');
    }
}
```

> it showing only employe table data how can i show the data for the
>   employes_detail as well as .still i am not able to understand it on
>   laravel documentation can anyone please help me related this.
>       how can i get the all data from employes and employes_details table for all the records

but when i used this code in controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $Employe=Employe::where('id',1)->first();
        //$convert=$Employe->toArray();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($Employe->employes_detail);exit;
        //return view('employe.employe');
    }
```

> its shows me the employe_detail table data
>       but i want both of the table data in a same array and i dont want to use where condition here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function `employes_detail` and `employe` in your models only declares the relationships between the models but if you want to load the relationship, you can try this :

`Employe::with('employes_detail')->get();`

or

`$employees = Employe::all(); $employees->load('employes_detail');`

Then you can access for each employees the relation attribute like that :

```
foreach($employees as $employe) {
    $employe->employes_detail->id;
}
```

Hopes it helps you.

Comment: Employe::with('employes_detail')->all(); i tried this but returning me the error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()

Comment: i did the same before you posted and its worked ..can u please explain why all() is not working

Comment: The `all` method is a magic method that you can call only on the model class, the function creates a query builder assign the model and call the `get()` method from the query builder.
When you call the `with` method it creates a query builder and assign the relationship you pass and then you can call the `get` method that is the difference.
That's why you can call `$employees = Employe::all(); $employees->load('relation');` and if you includes the with you need to call `get()`.

Comment: In employe_details table i have one field state where i am storing the id of the state table now how can i get the name of the satate

Comment: or how can i get the data in descending order can u please help me

Comment: in the `with` you can load multiple relations.
for descending order you can do `->with('relation')->orderBy('order');`

Comment: not getting the result getting error can you please update the controller code ?? its not working

Comment: `->with('relation')->orderBy('order')->get();`

Comment: I am not getting state name i was asking for only state name .. it means relation between studentdetail and state

Comment: Orderby ois working fine but i am asking about state table relation